# Android Wear: Work around for "com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"

Tags: android, wear-os

I used to use `com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER` and `WearableListenerService` to communicate between my Mobile and Wear device.

After the intent `com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER` getting deprecated I am supposed to use:

```
<service android:name=".MyListenerService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/prefix" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But how do I combine it with my `WearableListenerService`? where will the broadcast received?

Answer (score 0):

Like you said the `BIND_LISTENER` is deprecated now, so according to this [thread](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/04/deprecation-of-bindlistener.html), the alternative for this is by using a fine-grained intent filter mechanism that allows developers to specify exactly what events they are interested in.

There are [intent filters](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html)  for `DATA_CHANGED`, `MESSAGE_RECEIVED`, `CHANNEL_EVENT`, and `CAPABILITY_CHANGED`. You can specify multiple elements, and if any of them match, it will call your service and filter out anything else. If you do not include an element, all events will be filtered out and your service will never be called, so make sure to include at least one.

Check also the Live listener part and Best practice to know more information about this issue, including the use of [WearableListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService).

Comment: I am using DATA_CHANGED AND MESSAGE_RECEIVED. However, Ia m not receiving anything in my Wearable ListernerService